# Which method do I have to overwrite in Java to use ">" to compare instances of my class

Tags: java

As far as I understand I can overwrite `equals()` in Java to handle how my class interacts with `==`. Which method do I have to overwrite to be define the behavior of

```
MyClass obj1;
MyClass obj2;
if (obj1 > obj2){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to compare like this? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I understand I can overwrite equals() in Java to handle how my class interacts with ==

This is wrong. The explanation is already covered here: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1065197):

> `==` tests for reference equality.
>
> `.equals()` tests for value equality.

---

To your question:

Unlike C++ or C#, in Java you **cannot** overload operators.

Instead of using `>` and `<` operators you have two options.

1. Make `MyClass` implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

   ```
   public MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
       @Override
       public int compareTo(MyClass other) {
           //comparison logic here...
       }
   }
   ```

   You will use it like this:

   ```
   MyClass obj1 = ...;
   MyClass obj2 = ...;
   if (obj1.compareTo(obj2) > 0){
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Create a class that implements [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

   ```
   public class MyClassComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
       @Override
       public int compare(MyClass myClass1, MyClass myClass2) {
           //comparison logic here...
       }
   }
   ```

   You will use it like this:

   ```
   MyClass obj1 = ...;
   MyClass obj2 = ...;
   MyClassComparator comp = new MyClassComparator();
   if (comp.compare(obj1, obj2) > 0){
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: This won't let you use the > operator, however.

Comment: No worries, looks great now.  Cool beans.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. Java doesn't support custom operator overloading.
Overriding `equals` doesn't affect `==`.
The closest you can get to `<` is to implement the `Comparable` interface, which includes a `compareTo` method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html